# October CMS style form building

Tags: yaml, octobercms

I'm working on October CMS plugins for several days. I have noticed that, there is some YAML files. By defining the form fields easily in those files form field automatically builds and appears.

Also, I'm able to define relationships by using YAML files.

So, this is really a great idea to build forms easily. Can any body say me what this method named as? Are there any library to do this on my own project?

Answer (score 0):

This is a unique feature to October, some other CMS' do have features similar to this but none are quite as powerful. It is a mixture between Model column and field definitions coupled with a Form and List builder.

The closest library I can think of is called [Laravel Administrator](http://administrator.frozennode.com/), however I don't think it is executed quite as well but it could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

YAML is just a definition file, similar to XML. Laravel has normal PHP files ordered as arrays.

What I want to say is that YAML is just human-readable data serialization language. Each framework takes user input data and makes their own way of representing it. October CMS saves user configured data and stores it in db under system_settings table, I believe its transformed into JSON presentation and stored as text value.